# Active directory configuration on a shared remote workplace environment

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop

Our need is to allow users to log in to their online workplace (e.g. using Citrix), and have access to their office applications, as well as some of the internally hosted applications the servers in the same datacenter.

Suppose this remote workspace environment is on a platform that is shared by other external organizations. These different organizations are completely independent of each other and should be considered as 3rd parties that cannot be trusted.

As a client, I'm having doubts about this solution provided by the infrastructure provider.

- Is it safe to use a single Active Directory to configure all users, computers and security groups from all different organizations?
- What are the risks?
- And what can be done to mitigate those risks?
- Are there circumstances or configurations where having a single Active Directory would be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Ah! This makes more sense. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: 1. I think it's not the best idea. 2. Possibly information exposure 3. Possibly remove the windows executables which allow you to view other users, which would actually include Task Manager since you could see other online users there too.